# Issue regarding facebook log in kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

if i am adding "manage_pages" key for read permission the app is getting crashed any idea why? and how to solve it.
The permission is approved by Facebook in app review so issue there.

here is the code

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb];
[login logOut];
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"email",
                                   @"user_photos",
                                   @"public_profile",
                                   @"user_posts",
                                   @"user_likes",
                                   @"user_friends",
                                   @"user_hometown",
                                   @"user_work_history",
                                   @"user_location",
                                   @"user_birthday",
                                   @"user_about_me",
                                   @"user_managed_groups",
                                   @"manage_pages"
                                   ]
             fromViewController:controller
                        handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

                            if (error) {
                                NSLog(@"Process error");
                                callback(nil);
                            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                                callback(nil);
                            } else {
                                if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                                    NSString *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
                                    callback(accessToken);
                                }
                                else {
                                    callback(nil);
                                }
                            }
                        }];
```

Comment: Update your crash log here. Let me check

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g1g40d here is SS

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `manage_pages` key in publishPermissions. Not in `readPermissions`.

```
[login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"manage_pages"]
       fromViewController: ..
];
```